# HttpModule for a Response Filter - override Write or Close

Tags: asp.net, filter, httpmodule

What are the advantages/disadvantages of overriding Write instead of Close on the Filter Stream that does filtering in an HttpModule?

I assume you would want to use Write because the memory used by the buffer is smaller than using the entire byte array during Close.  Are there other reasons not to do manipulation in Close?